# rails bundle install sqlite3 failed in kali linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Please help me to resolve this problem I use kali linux os!!
root@artisla:~/Documents/Adilet/Programming/blog# gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/opt/local
Building native extensions with: '--with-sqlite3-dir=/opt/local'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150523-10092-2alrq5.rb extconf.rb --with-sqlite3-dir=/opt/local
```

checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/extensions/x86-linux/2.2.0/sqlite3-1.3.10/gem_make.out

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem just I had to change "sources.list" file.(source.list path "/etc/apt/sources.list") You get mirror list from there http://kaligr3y.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-add-full-repository-in-kali-linux.html